# How to search in comma separated value in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I want to search in comma separated value from a column in database. I know how to do this in MySQL query,

In MySQL:

```
SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', field)
```

but unable to find the alternative in Laravel.

here is what I have tried so far,

```
whereRaw(FIND_IN_SET(2,userid))
```

But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(2,sent_mail_ids)')
```

this must help you

Comment: it is helpful ? will you please let me know if i want to search with variable because it is showing error of comoumn not found... here is what i am trying 
  $userId = $request->input('userId'); 
$user_feedbacks   =  DB::table('abc') 
                               ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET($userId,askedFrom)')
                                ->get();

Answer (score 1):

Please Try the following code where **$c** is your search id like 1 or 2 or 3 etc and **column_name** is the your database table field name where search id store like 1,2,3 etc.

```
->whereRaw("find_in_set($c , column_name)");
```

means

```
->whereRaw("find_in_set('1' , column_name)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   // Receipt no.
    $fee_type_id = FeeType::select('id')->where('name', 'Main Fee')->first();

    // dd($fee_type_id);
    $receipt_group = FeeReceiptGroup::select('id', 'main_fee_status', 'receipt_group_id')->whereRaw('Find_IN_SET(?, fee_type_id)', [$fee_type_id->id])->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q->whereIn('tablecolumn', function ($query) use ($YourArray) {
 $query->select(\DB::raw('tablecolumn'))
  ->from('YourTableName') 
  ->where(function ($query) use ($YourArray) {
   foreach ($YourArray as $value) {
    $query->orWhereRaw("FIND_IN_SET($value, tablecolumn)");
   }
 });
});
```

> I found this solution and it works for me i have comma-seprated values in table and want to search by array values so it will be helpfull to you.